# Can coconut milk always and thoughtlessly substitute cream-based/bechamel sauces?

Tags: pasta, coconut

I'm thinking of a pasta dish with chicken and mushroom. I have some coconut milk to use. I also want to add cheese at the end, because cheese. But I'm worried the coconut milk might be too strong/odd a flavour, throw everything off?

What do you think?

Comment: We don't really answer questions about which flavour combinations are good, since that is entirely subjective. If you reframe your question as about if cheese will melt properly in a coconut based sauce that would be on topic.

Comment: With regard to above - on a personal note, I wouldn't dream of it. Swapping cream to coconut would shift *continent*. It would be more Caribbean or SE Asian than Italian.

Comment: But why not embrace a subjective conversation? Cooking is after all part science, part art.

Comment: We don't embrace subjective conversation, because time and again, we have seen that trying to have a subjective conversation on a site that rewards the most popular one of the early answers leads to the wrong kinds of information being misleadingly represented as absolute truth. If you want to have subjective conversations about cooking, you have to have them in a different kind of communication channel, not on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Like the [chat]...

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I just experimented with it.

A little essence of the coconut milk with some Emmental and cream cheese, was not a bad experience. It was interesting, if not a little bit odd - could be improved somehow, but it's not screaming at me to be explored.

Once I also added some of the other ingredients, namely the beef stock and the flavours from the mushrooms, peppers and garlic. There was a distinct oddness to the flavour, and I attribute that to the coconut milk.

So in short. I won't be repeating this adventure again.